# Solaris find command's print options

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, solaris

I am running the following command on cygwin

```
$ find . -printf "%p %m %s \n" | sort -n
```

and the output is below...

```
./.metadata/.log 700 17247
./.metadata/.mylyn 700 0
./.metadata/.mylyn/repositories.xml.zip 700 423
./.metadata/.mylyn/tasks.xml.zip 700 250
./.metadata/.plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.core/appengine-sdk-proxy.jar 700 8782
```

(required out format is filename/permission in octal/size in bytes)

I would like to know how to create a similar output on Solaris. (the above command does not work on solaris)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Perl to glean the same info as find's `-printf`:

```
find . -print | perl -lne '$,=" "; @s=stat $_; print $_, $s[2], $s[7]'
```

Comment: In the unlikely event that a filename contains a newline, this will miss that file.  No one should be making filenames like that, and lots of other things would probably break too, but it is legal.

Answer (score 0):

There really is no simple way to duplicate this without writing a fair amount of code.

```
http://www.sunfreeware.com/indexsparc10.html
```

This is an index to sparc for Solaris 10 - free downloads from sunfreeware.  If you are on x86 there is a corresponding download.  You want to download and install

```
findutils-4.4.2-sol10-sparc-local.gz
```

There are some dependencies that go with it.  Otherwise you face writing a good bit of shell, C or perl to duplicate the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can get close with `-ls`:

```
$ find . -ls | awk '{print $11 " " $3 " " $7 }'
```

However, that will get you the symbolic permissions, not the octal perms.

Comment: `$11` won't contain the complete filename if the filename contains spaces.

Answer (score 0):

This should work on any Unix / Unix like OS, i.e. doesn't requires gnu find, perl or similar:

```
PATH=`getconf PATH`
LC_ALL=C find . -exec ls -dils {} + | awk '
function parse(s,level)
{
    p=0;
    r=substr(s, 1 ,1)
    w=substr(s, 2 ,1)
    x=substr(s, 3 ,1)
    if(r=="r") p+=4;
    if(w=="w") p+=2;
    if(x=="x") p+=1;
    if(x!="-" && x!="x") { p+=1; xtra+=level }
    return(p)
}
function s2n(s)
{
    xtra=0
    owner=parse(substr(s, 2 , 3), 4)
    group=parse(substr(s, 5 , 3), 2)
    other=parse(substr(s, 8 , 3), 1)
    return(0+(xtra*1000)+(owner*100)+(group*10)+other);
}
{
    perm=s2n($3);
    size=$7
    $1=$2=$3=$4=$5=$6=$7=$8=$9=$10=""
    sub("^ *","")
    print $0 " " perm " " size
}'
```

Comment: `find` on Solaris may not have the `+` terminator for the `-exec` option.

Comment: @glenn jackman : Actually not. While undocumented until Solaris 9, this + terminator has been available since the first Solaris 2 release a couple of decades ago.